# Python lxml prevent less than < or greater > from being converted to &lt and &gt

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, lxml

I am using lxml to generate a large XML file.  One of the tags used in the file is "lambda" so I cannot define it as I normally would. (and no, I cannot change the name of the tag)

Code:

```
import lxml.etree as ETree
import lxml.builder as lxmlBuilder

E = lxmlBuilder.ElementMaker()
root = E.root
lbd = E.lambda  #error since lambda is reserved

myTree = root(
     lbd('1')
    )

print ETree.tostring(myTree, pretty_print=True)
```

Intended Result:

```
<root>
    <lambda>1</lambda>
</root>
```

Since this is the case, I just wanted to enter the "lambda" tags manually.  However, when I try to do this, the "less than" or "greater than" symbols around "lambda" are converted to &lt and &gt.
Code:

```
E = lxmlBuilder.ElementMaker()
root = E.root
lbd = "<lambda>%f</lambda>" % 1 #by hand

myTree = root(
     lbd
    )

print ETree.tostring(myTree, pretty_print=True)
```

Result:

```
<root>
    &lt;lambda&gt;1.0000&lt;/lambda&gt;
</root>
```

How can I prevent the < and > symbols from being converted like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `lbd = getattr(E, 'lambda')` instead of `lbd = E.lambda` to overcome the limitation due to the reserved keyword.

```
>>> import lxml.etree as ETree
>>> import lxml.builder as lxmlBuilder
>>> E = lxmlBuilder.ElementMaker()
>>> root = E.root
>>> lbd = getattr(E, 'lambda')
>>> myTree = root(lbd('1'))
>>> ETree.tostring(myTree, pretty_print=True)
b'<root>\n  <lambda>1</lambda>\n</root>\n'
```